# Picard's uniqueness theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dt} =ay; y(0)=0$$ satisfies the condition of Picard's uniqueness theorem. But, I find that it can have multiple solution. How lipschitz condition helping to get a unique solution ?

Comment: Is $a$ just a real number? If so, this *does* have a unique solution.

Comment: @T.Bongers:  $y(t) =0$ and $y(t) = e^{at} -1$ are two solutions.

Comment: $e^{at} - 1$ is not a solution.

Comment: @T.Bongers: I took the $y$ in the left side and then integrate both sides. That gave me $y=e^{at} + c$ where $c$ is a constant. Then $y(0) = 0$ gives me the answer. Where am I doing the mistake (as it is clear that $e^{at} -1 $ is not a solution).

Comment: You should get $\ln |y(t)| = at + c$ or $y(t)=0$, thus $y(t) = \pm e^c \cdot e^{at}$ (*times*, not plus) or $y(t)=0$. The initial condition $y(0)=0$ picks out the solution $y(t)=0$.